# How to expand partition in dual boot system

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I am not the person who first partitioned the hard drive. I am just the person assigned to fixing it. Secondly, I am a complete novice when it comes to Linux and dual boot environments.

System: Dual boot Windows and Ubuntu

Problem: I need to expand the C drive as it is out of space however the unallocated space is non-adjacent to the C drive. In between the two partitions are the hard drive partitions for Ubuntu. Is there a way to rearrange and move the partitions so I am able to extend the C drive? Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?

[image: Screenshot of Windows Disk Management]

Comment: You would have to delete the existing partitions between your system partition and the unallocated partition to do what you describe.  GParted can do a a lot of cool things but it can’t extend a partition with nonajacent sectors

Answer (score 0):

[GParted Live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) can be used for that, but don't forget to backup all your data before playing with your partitions.